# I have a problem with signing by google in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, google-authenticator

I have a problem with signing using my Google account in an ASP.NET Core project; when I try to login in, I face this issue: I run project on http localhost, I think I should run in https localhost but I can't run Visual Studio with https:

[image]

This is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallBack", "Account",
            new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });

        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallBack(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        returnUrl =
            (returnUrl != null && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) ? returnUrl : Url.Content("~/");

        var loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel()
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
            ExternalLogins = (await AccountService.GetExternalLogins()).ToList()
        };

        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", $"Error : {remoteError}");
            return View("Login", loginViewModel);
        }

        var externalLoginInfo = await AccountService.ExternalLoginInfo();
        if (externalLoginInfo == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ErrorLoadingExternalLoginInfo", $"مشکلی پیش آمد");
            return View("Login", loginViewModel);
        }

        var signInResult = await AccountService.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(externalLoginInfo.LoginProvider,
            externalLoginInfo.ProviderKey);

        if (signInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        var email = externalLoginInfo.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

        if (email != null)
        {
            var user = await AccountService.GetUserByEmail(email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                var userName = email.Split('@')[0];
                user = new IdentityUser()
                {
                    UserName = (userName.Length <= 10 ? userName : userName.Substring(0, 10)),
                    Email = email,
                    EmailConfirmed = true
                };

                AccountService.AddUser(user);
            }

            AccountService.AddLoginAsync(user, externalLoginInfo);
            AccountService.LoginUser(user);

            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        ViewBag.ErrorTitle = "لطفا با بخش پشتیبانی تماس بگیرید";
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"دریافت کرد {externalLoginInfo.LoginProvider} نمیتوان اطلاعاتی از";
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
```

and this is my *startup.cs*

[image]

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Correlation failed usually points to cookie mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Add this you're configure method in your `startup.cs` I think it will resolve your issue.

**UPDATE**

```
 app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions()
{
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax
});
```

Also, you can try this.but make sure remove `app.UseCookiePolicy();` code in the `Configure` method:-

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

Comment: My first answer,i think your forgot to remove ```app.UseCookiePolicy();``` I answered your question's solution two types of process.it should resolve your issue. Check my updated answer.

Comment: i faced with new problems   OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.  TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.  TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.  Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.

Comment: @rezasetareh Can you have tried two types of the answer and found this error the same for these?

Comment: @rezasetareh post your whole ```startup.cs``` code.

Comment: i posted my whole startup code please check

Comment: @rezasetareh   **public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });**  try this code up in your configure service like that.sorry for late for my network problem and then what happen let me know.

Comment: nothing happend dear.i wish you could connect my laptop and check it online i really confused :(

Comment: im from iran may be we are under google sanction i dont know

Comment: Can you send me your telegram id or whats up number please @Pritom

Comment: @rezasetareh  I am actually was want to connect your computer via TeamViewer.because I will gonna the last try for this issue.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234296/discussion-between-pritom-sarkar-and-reza-setareh    go to this link then reply to me.it's going to the long conversation in the comment box.

Comment: Sorry I have less than 20 reputation to talk